# How to add elements to the application menu in OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qml, qt5

Is it possible to change the Application Menu on OSX?

The default application menu looks like the following:

[image: No additional menu entry]

But most applications provide things like the about window in the application menu to not clutter the help menu:

[image: additional menu entries]

How can this be done in Qt? A solution in QML would be great, but there isn't even a general solution in the project examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force action into the application menu, set a menu role on it:

```
action->setMenuRole(QAction::ApplicationSpecificRole);
```

Comment: I guess this isn't (yet) possible from QML?